# Parse PHP out of string using Regex

Tags: php, sql, regex, parsing

I have thousands of lines following the structure below:

```
$this->addSql("INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (45824, 'TCP', 'DAI ', 0)");
$this->addSql("INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (47001, 'TCP', 'WinRM', 0)");
$this->addSql("INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (47808, 'UDP', 'BACnet', 0)");
$this->addSql("INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (48653, 'TCP', 'Robot', 0)");
$this->addSql("INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (48653, 'UDP', 'Robot', 0)");
$this->addSql("INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (49151, 'TCP', 'Reserved', 0)");
```

How can I parse out the php on the beginning and end of the lines so I can have just a valid sql statement to use?

Thanks

Comment: Why not open in into a text editor and use the find and replace functionality?

Comment: The word "parsing" is used somewhat inflationary. This is also just text matching / rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing it, you can execute it.

If you wrap it in a piece of code that outputs it (to screen, to file, to whatever...), you can capture all the queries anyway you like. This is especially useful if the sql strings may contain variables or escaped characters too. That would make parsing harder, but if you just execute the code, PHP will do the hard work for you.

```
class Output {

  function addSql($sql) {
     echo "$sql\n";
  }

  function output() {

     // Paste that code of yours here

  }

}

$x = new Output();
$x->output();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cut`:

```
cut -d '"' -f2 file.sql
INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (45824, 'TCP', 'DAI ', 0)
INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (47001, 'TCP', 'WinRM', 0)
INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (47808, 'UDP', 'BACnet', 0)
INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (48653, 'TCP', 'Robot', 0)
INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (48653, 'UDP', 'Robot', 0)
INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (49151, 'TCP', 'Reserved', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in PHP you could use a regex with

```
"(.*)"
```

which would return the string as a group. [Here for test](https://regex101.com/r/qQ9mS1/1)

EDIT: for those that didn't want to follow the link, here's an implementation in PHP.

```
$re = "/\"(.*)\"/"; 
$str = "\$this->addSql(\"INSERT INTO PortsList (Port, Proto, Name, Encrypted) VALUES (45824, 'TCP', 'DAI ', 0)\")"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: You need to add the `g` flag to match all occurrences.

Comment: @Mike there's no `g` flag in PHP.

Comment: you need to use a `findall` version of the regex if you really have a block of all lines, or iterate through each line and build up your data. either approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but only works on the sql lines.
Replace with empty string.

`'~(?m)(?:^[^"\r\n]*\(\h*"\h*|\h*"\h*\)[^"()\r\n]*$)~'`

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?m)                    # Multi-line mode
 (?:
      ^                       # BOL
      [^"\r\n]* \(    
      \h* " \h* 
   |                        # or,
      \h* " \h*          
      \) [^"()\r\n]* 
      $                       # EOL
 )
```